# debug kubelet not starting

Tags: centos7, kubernetes

I'm using `kubeadm` to try to setup a dev master.  I'm running into an issue where the healthcheck for kubelet is failing.  I'm looking for direction on how to debug that.  Running the command that's suggested for debugging (`systemctl status kubelet`) don't see the cause of the error:

```
kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
           └─10-kubeadm.conf
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-10-05 15:04:23 CDT; 4s ago
     Docs: http://kubernetes.io/docs/
  Process: 4786 ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_SYSTEM_PODS_ARGS $KUBELET_NETWORK_ARGS $KUBELET_DNS_ARGS $KUBELET_AUTHZ_ARGS $KUBELET_CADVISOR_ARGS $KUBELET_CGROUP_ARGS $KUBELET_CERTIFICATE_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 4786 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 05 15:04:23 master.domain..com systemd[1]: Unit kubelet.service entered failed state.
Oct 05 15:04:23 master.domain.com systemd[1]: kubelet.service failed.
```

**Where can I find a specific error message to indicate why this isn't running?**

> After running `swapoff -a` to disable swap, I'm still not able to provision Kubernetes.

Here's the full output from `kubeadm init`:

```
$ kubeadm init
[kubeadm] WARNING: kubeadm is in beta, please do not use it for production clusters.
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.8.2
[init] Using Authorization modes: [Node RBAC]
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
[preflight] WARNING: docker version is greater than the most recently validated version. Docker version: 17.09.0-ce. Max validated version: 17.03
[preflight] Starting the kubelet service
[kubeadm] WARNING: starting in 1.8, tokens expire after 24 hours by default (if you require a non-expiring token use --token-ttl 0)
[certificates] Generated ca certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated apiserver certificate and key.
[certificates] apiserver serving cert is signed for DNS names [master.my-domain.com kubernetes kubernetes.default kubernetes.default.svc kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local] and IPs [10.xx.xx.xx 10.xx.xx.xx]
[certificates] Generated apiserver-kubelet-client certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated sa key and public key.
[certificates] Generated front-proxy-ca certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated front-proxy-client certificate and key.
[certificates] Valid certificates and keys now exist in "/etc/kubernetes/pki"
[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "admin.conf"
[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "kubelet.conf"
[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "controller-manager.conf"
[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "scheduler.conf"
[controlplane] Wrote Static Pod manifest for component kube-apiserver to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml"
[controlplane] Wrote Static Pod manifest for component kube-controller-manager to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml"
[controlplane] Wrote Static Pod manifest for component kube-scheduler to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml"
[etcd] Wrote Static Pod manifest for a local etcd instance to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/etcd.yaml"
[init] Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as Static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
[init] This often takes around a minute; or longer if the control plane images have to be pulled.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10255/healthz' failed with error: Get http://localhost:10255/healthz: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10255: getsockopt: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10255/healthz' failed with error: Get http://localhost:10255/healthz: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10255: getsockopt: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10255/healthz' failed with error: Get http://localhost:10255/healthz: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10255: getsockopt: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10255/healthz/syncloop' failed with error: Get http://localhost:10255/healthz/syncloop: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10255: getsockopt: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10255/healthz/syncloop' failed with error: Get http://localhost:10255/healthz/syncloop: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10255: getsockopt: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10255/healthz/syncloop' failed with error: Get http://localhost:10255/healthz/syncloop: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10255: getsockopt: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10255/healthz' failed with error: Get http://localhost:10255/healthz: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10255: getsockopt: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10255/healthz/syncloop' failed with error: Get http://localhost:10255/healthz/syncloop: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10255: getsockopt: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10255/healthz' failed with error: Get http://localhost:10255/healthz: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10255: getsockopt: connection refused.

Unfortunately, an error has occurred:
    timed out waiting for the condition

This error is likely caused by that:
    - The kubelet is not running
    - The kubelet is unhealthy due to a misconfiguration of the node in some way (required cgroups disabled)
    - There is no internet connection; so the kubelet can't pull the following control plane images:
        - gcr.io/google_containers/kube-apiserver-amd64:v1.8.2
        - gcr.io/google_containers/kube-controller-manager-amd64:v1.8.2
        - gcr.io/google_containers/kube-scheduler-amd64:v1.8.2

You can troubleshoot this for example with the following commands if you're on a systemd-powered system:
    - 'systemctl status kubelet'
    - 'journalctl -xeu kubelet'
couldn't initialize a Kubernetes cluster
```

I've also tried removing the docker repository and installing Docker 1.12 which isn't runnable - `Error starting daemon: SELinux is not supported with the overlay graph driver on this kernel. Either boot into a newer kernel or disable selinux ...`

Comment: see if there are logs for it in /var/log or /var/log/kubernetes not sure where kubeadm puts things

Comment: @Mike I can't find logs anywhere, I think it's outputting everything rather than logging.

Comment: best thing to do is look at the systemd service file.. source the env vars and run the command to see the output

Comment: `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service` looks like just a yml file

Answer (score 4):

Things were  solved by setting `--fail-swap-on=false` in the systemd script.
Just make the modification on the file `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf`

```
Environment="KUBELET_SYSTEM_PODS_ARGS=--pod-manifest-path=/etc/kubernetes/manifests --allow-privileged=true --fail-swap-on=false"
```

then run `systemctl daemon-reload` and then `systemctl restart kubelet`

Comment: This has not resolved the issue for me.

Comment: I am trying to do it but I am getting with the user. It said the user is not running as root.

Answer (score 4):

Found an issue regarding this: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/53333

Following the previous answer worked for me, but not the resolution offered in the linked issue.

So perhaps, following their suggestion of editing 90-kubeadm.conf (in place of 10-kubeadm.conf) would work

Answer (score 4):

I have had the same issue but on Fedora 30, kubelet 1.15.3, docker-ce 19.03.1
And the output of `systemctl status kubelet` was contained same as in your case:

```
Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
           └─10-kubeadm.conf
```

Steps to solve were:
1. check if you have files kubelet.service and 10-kubeadm.conf on the next paths:

```
ls /usr/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf
ls /usr/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service
```

10-kubeadm.conf:

```
more /usr/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf 

# Note: This dropin only works with kubeadm and kubelet v1.11+
[Service]
Environment="KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS=--bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf"
Environment="KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS=--config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
# This is a file that "kubeadm init" and "kubeadm join" generates at runtime, populating the KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS variable dynamically
EnvironmentFile=-/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env
# This is a file that the user can use for overrides of the kubelet args as a last resort. Preferably, the user should use
# the .NodeRegistration.KubeletExtraArgs object in the configuration files instead. KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS should be sourced from this file.
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/kubelet
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS
```

kubelet.service:

```
more /usr/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service

[Unit]
Description=Kubernetes Kubelet Server
Documentation=https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes
After=docker.service
Requires=docker.service

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/lib/kubelet
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/kubernetes/config
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/kubernetes/kubelet
ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet \
        $KUBE_LOGTOSTDERR \
        $KUBE_LOG_LEVEL \
        $KUBELET_API_SERVER \
        $KUBELET_ADDRESS \
        $KUBELET_PORT \
        $KUBELET_HOSTNAME \
        $KUBE_ALLOW_PRIV \
        $KUBELET_ARGS
Restart=on-failure
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

2. Delete systemd unit for kubelet in /etc/systemd/system/

   ```
   rm -R /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d (confirm "y" for each file)
   rm /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service
   ```
3. Reload all systemd unit files, and recreate the entire dependency tree.

   `systemctl daemon-reload`
4. restart kubelet

   `systemctl restart kubelet`

The output of kubelet status then should contain:

```
  Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
           └─10-kubeadm.conf
```

5. Initialize a Kubernetes control-plane node:

   ```
   kubeadm reset
   systemctl daemon-reload
   kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
   ```

Note: You have one or more issue:

> ```
> `- There is no internet connection; so the kubelet can't pull the following control plane images:`
> ```

Try to pull them manually:

```
kubeadm config images pull
```

You may need to upgrade kubeadm, kubelet, kebectl

Answer (score 2):

check the error from:  journalctl -xeu kubelet

Note: Make sure that the cgroup driver used by kubelet is the same as the one used by Docker. To ensure compatability you can either update Docker, like so:

```
cat << EOF > /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=systemd"]
}
EOF
```

Comment: After that you have to "systemctl restart docker" and works!

Answer (score 1):

This is all already covered in the issue that Atom posted, so I don't feel like I'm contributing an awful lot, but I can replicate your issue if swap is turned on. So for me the solution is to disable swap and retry the init:

```
sudo -i
swapoff -a
kubeadm reset
kubeadm init
```

The answer posted by dirtbag worked for me as well, but just to be safe after `systemctl daemon-reload`, I did a full `kubeadm reset` and `kubeadm init`, not just a `systemctl restart kubelet`.

If this doesn't work for you, can you please paste the new output of `kubeadm init` after disabling swap?

Comment: That does allow me to remove the flag from `kubeadm.conf` and makes the warning `[preflight] WARNING: docker version is greater than the most recently validated version. Docker version: 17.09.0-ce. Max validated version: 17.03` appear.  I also tried running `kube init  --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16` as described in the flannel instructions with no luck.

Comment: New init output has been posted above.

Comment: Looking at https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/#installing-docker they do say:

`On each of your machines, install Docker. Version v1.12 is recommended, but v1.11, v1.13 and 17.03 are known to work as well. Versions 17.06+ might work, but have not yet been tested and verified by the Kubernetes node team.`

Perhaps it's worth retrying with a supported Docker version? I used `1.12.6` for my test. This was the default version I got on a fresh Centos7 after doing `yum install epel-release` and `yum install docker`.

Comment: I just did that, docker 1.12 won't run `Error starting daemon: SELinux is not supported with the overlay graph driver on this kernel. Either boot into a newer kernel or disable selinux`...

Comment: Disabling SELinux was also encouraged by the kubeadm documentation. To disable selinux until reboot run `setenforce 0`. To disable permanently, edit `/etc/selinux/config` and change `SELINUX=enforcing` to `SELINUX=permissive`. I assume this is a development environment and disabling SELinux isn't too big of an issue!

Comment: It's currently set to permissive.  I ran `setenforce 0` as well.  I'm still in the same spot.

Comment: Anymore suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

1. sudo vim /etc/modules-load.d/k8s.conf
2. Make sure to have these settings there:

- `net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 1`
- `net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1`

Answer (score 0):

first need to create conf file
https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/kubelet-integration/#the-kubelet-drop-in-file-for-systemd

then enable kubelet

we need to run kubeadm init on master or kubeadm reset on worker nodes to generate conf files

Answer (score 0):

Make sure swap space is off.

#swapoff -a

manual way -

comment out any line with 'swap' word in /etc/fstab.

after doing it manually run swapoff -a command once again.

then restart kubelet service -
#systemctl restart kubelet